# Rewrite .htaccess 2 GET variables not splitting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Trying to write a rewrite rule to capture two GET variables

```
http://stackoverflow.com/blogs/category/general/1

RewriteRule ^blogs/category/(.+)/?$ blogs.php?category=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/category/(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$ blogs.php?category=$1&page=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
```

However when I grab these from the headers it looks like this?

```
$_GET['category'] = "general/1";
$_GET['page'] = "";
```

As you can see I have two rules, one for just when they provide category and one for when they also provide page number. Might be wrong about that approach I'm not sure.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I separate these variables properly using the rewrite rules (I know I could hack it in php but that's ugly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to switch them so that the more specific one is handled first:

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/category/(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$ blogs.php?category=$1&page=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/category/(.+)/?$ blogs.php?category=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

To explain that a little bit further: All regular expressions are greedy if not specified otherwise. Which means, that the regular expression tries to get as much as possible. (.+) matches "general/1".